# ios photo/video capture/usage using c++

Tags: c++, ios

hi there i need some help. 
i already made an android app that take a pic/video, send it to a server which do some stuff and return a string . on the android app taking the photo/video was done using the java code, the path is sent to a C++ code which with help of NDK send the data to the server and get the string back. then pass the string to java for display and delete the photo/video.

now i need to do the same on ios.
is there a way to get a photo/video from camera, and then pass the path to my c++ code that will be the same as in my android app?
thanks

(Edit)
Let me describe the question better. 
i need an objective c code, that will take an image/video from the camera (i could find the tutorial camera apps of apple and many other sites) what i need now to add is a code that will get me the absolute path to the media file so that i can pass it to the C++ code)

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 has some c++ development environment for iOS. You should check there.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Copying the image/video file to a temporary folder and creating a c++ string representing the file path to inject that into your library?

Comment: more or less. i need to get the image path so my c++ code can fread() it. and send the buffer to a server. then the image/video is of no interest for me and actually i need it to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I found this artical  how to access C/C++ Lib in iOS Objective-C++
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-in-an-ios-app-with-objective-c/

Comment: thank you for the response maybe i wasn't clear. i know abt objective c++ my concern is how to take the picture / video using objective c, then take the path to send it to c++.